# Merge problems with SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, merge

I'm Trying to merge the two Tables

```
NAME    AGE SALARY      CITY
Mike    29  42000.00    SAN BERNARDINO
Chris   28  52000.00    FRESNO
Shawn   27  35000.00    SACRAMENTO
Chris   28  52000.00    FRESNO

ID  NAME    AGE SALARY  CITY
1   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
2   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
3   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
4   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

I want the end result to look like this below

```
ID  NAME    AGE SALARY      CITY
1   Mike    29  42000.00    SAN BERNARDINO
2   Chris   28  52000.00    FRESNO
3   Shawn   27  35000.00    SACRAMENTO
4   Chris   28  52000.00    FRESNO


Instead it looks like this below

ID  NAME    AGE SALARY  CITY
1   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
2   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
3   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
4   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    Mike    29  42000.00    SAN BERNARDINO
NULL    Chris   28  52000.00    FRESNO
NULL    Shawn   27  35000.00    SACRAMENTO
NULL    Chris   28  52000.00    FRESNO
```

I ended up with this as my best result so far using the insert into option and was wondering. I know I could just use update or something to do it one by one but I don't think that would be great for a bigger table. I made a database without a primary key and was just seeing how I could fix it mainly.

```
INSERT INTO SAMPLE (NAME, AGE, SALARY, CITY)
SELECT NAME, AGE, SALARY, CITY
FROM SAMPLE2
```

I'm not sure what to change in the code or how to go about it.

EDIT: I can't even use this site right rip..

Comment: Why Mike has ID =1? Does an order of assignment matter?

Comment: No, it does not.

Comment: What is your MySql version?

Comment: The most current I just downloaded it yesterday.

Comment: Your query looks like it should work. What problem are you having with it?

Comment: So instead of only being 4 rows, it's making 8 rows. I'm trying to insert the data from the 4 rows in the first table Into the first 4 rows of the second table.

Comment: instead of merging the two tables..it would be better if you update your existing table 1 and create a primary key column (ID) in it. My point is why to maintain a second table just to hold ID??

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to assign an id to your rows, its a better approach something like this:

```
with data as (
  select 'Mike' as NAME,   29 AS AGE, 42000.00 AS SALARY, 'SAN BERNARDINO' AS CITY union all
  select 'Chris',28,52000.00,'FRESNO' union all
  select 'Shawn',27,35000.00,'SACRAMENTO' union all
  select 'Chris',28,52000.00,'FRESNO'
)
select 
  row_number() over (partition by null) as ID,
  d.*
from data d
```

Answer (score 0):

You can artificially create `ID` using `row_number()` function for `SAMPLE2` and update `SAMPLE`.

```
 with cte as (
    select
        *,
        ROW_NUMBER() over (order by CITY) as nr
    from SAMPLE2
)
update SAMPLE s
join cte c
    on s.ID = c.nr
set  s.NAME = c.NAME
    ,s.AGE = c.AGE
    ,s.SALARY = c.SALARY
    ,s.CITY = c.CITY;
```